# Get HTML source code of page with PHP

Tags: php, html

If I have the html file:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
  <head></head>
   <body>
    <!-- Begin -->
    Important Information
    <!-- End -->
   </body>
  </head>
 </html>
```

How can I use PHP to get the string "Important Information" from the file?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html

Comment: It isn't (mostly) the parsing i'm worried about, more getting the code in the first place

Comment: How can I turn "<!doctype html>
 <html>
  <head></head>
   <body>
    <!-- Begin -->
    Important Information
    <!-- End -->
   </body>
  </head>
 </html>" Into a php $variable?

Comment: Title is highly misleading, you're not "getting the HTML source code." You're just getting the text.

Comment: No sorry, I am, how can I turn index.html into php $variable?

Comment: What do you suggest I edit the title into?

Comment: Your question asks how to extract the content between the HTML comment nodes. That's what you use a parser for. Please update your question if that's not what you want to do.

Comment: @Gordon I actually found the initial version of the question more explanatory in what he wanted to do.  He wasn't asking how to parse the file, he was asking how to actually open and read the file as a string into a single variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already have the parsing sorted, just use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).  You can pass it a URL and it will return the content found at the URL, in this case, the html.  Or if you have the file locally, you pass it the file path.

Answer (score 2):

In this simple example you can open the file and do `fgets()` until you find a line with `<!-- Begin -->` and saving the lines until you find `<!-- End -->`.

If your HTML is in a variable you can just do:

```
<?php
$begin = strpos($var, '<!-- Begin -->') + strlen('<!-- Begin -->'); // Can hardcode this with 14 (the length of your 'needle'
$end   = strpos($var, '<!-- End -->');

$text = substr($var, $begin, ($end - $begin));

echo $text;
?>
```

You can see the output [here](http://ideone.com/kGO4G).

Comment: How can I use fgets with a $var?

Comment: Don't forget the whitespace before `<!-- Begin -->`

Comment: Is this `$var` a string with the HTML content?

Answer (score -1):

You can fetch "HTML" by this

```
//file_get_html function from third party library
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/');
```

and any operation on DOM then read following docs:
http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: There is no `file_get_html` in `DOM` or in PHP.

Comment: @Manish simplehtmldom is a third party library and not a native PHP extension. You linked to `DOM` in your answer.

Comment: @gordon:: I'm not mention it. Sorry for this

Comment: *(tip)* when you know your answer is wrong, correct it. People might remove the downvote then.